# Xaringan: center image within one of two columns in a two columns layout

Tags: r, xaringan

I am using a two-column layout and I was wondering if I could center the image *within* the second column.

This is the YAML:

```
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: 
author: 
date: " </br> `r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: ["default", "custom.css", "custom-fonts.css"]
    nature:
      beforeInit: "http://www.jvcasillas.com/ru_xaringan/js/ru_xaringan.js"
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      ratio: "16:9"
---
```

The slide:

```
---
# Introduction

.pull-left[
- One bullet.
-  Another bullet.
- another 
- another
- another

]
.pull-right[

<img src="img/book.jpg" alt="drawing" width="200"/>

]
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the image is "hanging" from the top left corner of the second column. I was wondering if I could have it centered within the second column.

Comment: .pull-right[
  .center[
  <img src="img/book.jpg" alt="drawing" width="200"/>
  ]
]
If you want it centered horizontally. You can also use .middle if you want to center vertically.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where can I learn more about this syntax? For example, how to place an image at a certain distance from the border, slide by slide?

Comment: Alison Hill has great content about doing slides with rmarkdown,https://alison.rbind.io/. You may also find good content from https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/.

Comment: I am familiar with their websites, but I have never seen something like `.pull-right[ .center[ ` (maybe I missed it.) That's css, right? But if google for "css pull right centering" for example, I find something like:  `<img class="center-block" src="img/book.jpg" / >` that does not work in xaringan.

Comment: Yes, that creates custom css. You can also create your own custom classes and apply them like that. I think that .center[] comes by default with remark js, which is what is used by xaringan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [Tomas Capretto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12266277/tomas-capretto)'s suggestion:

```
---
# Introduction

.pull-left[
- One bullet.
-  Another bullet.
- another 
- another
- another

]

.pull-right[ .center[ <img src="img/book.jpg" alt="drawing" width="200"/> ] ]
```

Here is the result:

[image]